# How might a race of humanoids with haplodiploid sex determination reproduce artificially?

Tags: science-based, biology, technology, reproduction

I'd like to have unique fantasy type 'races' in a world which appears as a typical fantasy world, but is in fact set far in the future after an apocalyptic event.

I'd like one of these races to be 'ant people'. In other words, I want them to be both eusocial and exhibit [haplodiploid sex determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplodiploidy) with the majority of the population being sterile alloparents. Because this is a post apocalyptic setting and set in the future, they should also be descended from humans. I imagine them as primarily subterranean bunker or hive dwellers.

However, from what I could find, the evolution of haplodiploidy in mammals looks like it would be quite unlikely, and as far as I know, an individual with a single X chromosome is unlikely to both live to maturity and be able to reproduce as a male (see [Monosomy X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turner_syndrome), although I suspect that the actual human equivalent to a haploid male would not even survive gestation if I understand correctly). This is on top of the fact that a 'queen' with a reproductive rate even nearing that of bees or ants seems very unrealistic, and the fact that the [parthenogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis) required to produce males also seems unlikely to evolve in mammals.

My solution was that all reproductive activities would be carried out artificially/non-biologically, wherein two 'queens' need only input their genetic material into a machine and that machine gestates the required young for the queen donating the 'female' portion of the DNA (I'm handwaving the motivations for the creation of every element of this until these can be fleshed out later). My question is, how could this be accomplished technically? I understand that advanced [artificial wombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_womb) beyond what we have today would be required for gestation, and that the process might involve or be similar to human cloning (which as far as I understand is also somewhat speculative), but other than that I'm a bit out of my depth. What kind of rough process/tools would be required to pull this off? Just how 'science fiction' are these tools?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want the designs of a machine that would carry that out? The Rick and Morty episode "Raising Gazorpazorp" kind of covers the amount of interaction that this would require. Are you looking for a social structure that would support this? Unfortunately, you are going so far afield that there's no precedent on which to even comment.

Comment: @RobertRapplean do you have any recommendations on how I could improve the question?

Comment: Let's try this: What aspects of the process do you feel would be relevant to your story line?

Comment: I thought about it. I would suggest that you ask "What technologies would be required to create an artificial womb?" I think that the haplodiploid part of it distracts from what you want to know.

Comment: @RobertRapplean Degree of realism: If what I've tried to communicate is essentially magical thinking or 'very soft' sci-fi, It doesn't really have a place in the story I'm creating. It would also be nice to be able to allude to what's actually functionally going on within the story with more antiquated language.

Comment: @RobertRapplean I don't think that's quite it. If I wanted to do cloned organisms, I would already know the answer, because I have a rough outline of SCNT cloning and how it works in my head, but this is a different process altogether that I haven't a clue about. I've obviously miscommunicated the question, so I may try to reword it and try again later.

Comment: Realism for what? Are you asking how these people normally procreate? I really think that's up to you. Are you ideating what their sex bots look like? Is there something about the egg/sperm interaction that we don't know about? Do you need pointers on how a placenta works? These questions are where my mind goes when I read this, so you're going to have to narrow it down for us.

Comment: Many try to be as realistic as possible, but that quest has significant limitaitons. So much so that it spawned [this meta question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10029/40609). The problem is you're asking us to provide a science-based answer to a science-fiction question - making your fantasy real.  It is worth reading [Advice concerning questions asking HOW to implement a technological procedure or device](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8273/40609) - because (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... anyone who can answer what you've asked to the level of detail you appear to be asking for would be running for the patent office, not explaining it here. Consequently, what are your goals? Because we're very good at using science to rationalize fiction and create the necessary suspension of disbelief - but inventing technology in the Real World is out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

> However, from what I could find, the evolution of haplodiploidy in mammals looks like it would be quite unlikely

You're the boss; handwave in what you want. The trick is to not try to explain anything in too much detail, because that explanation and those details are where you can be *wrong*.

> My solution was that all reproductive activities would be carried out artificially/non-biologically, wherein two 'queens' need only input their genetic material into a machine and that machine gestates the required young

You've already kinda answered your own question here... you've got some form of  [in-vitro fertilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_vitro_fertilisation), plumbed in to some form of [artificial womb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_womb). The former process is relatively well described in the real world, but the latter remains more or less science-fiction and as such there isn't really any way for people to give you a really good answer to "*What kind of rough process/tools would be required to pull this off?*" without doing a some sort of experimental biology and medicine literature review for you. I don't really know enough about the subject to do that for you, but the top wikipedia reference an article in Nature, [An extra-uterine system to physiologically support the extreme premature lamb](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5414058/) seems like a reasonable start... looks like a sort of baby [sous-vide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sous_vide). If in doubt, though, apply the same advice as above: details and explanations can be wrong. Your readers (or players, or whatever) can live without the gory engineering details of your baby-brewing bioreactors.

However, wombs, placentas and gestation are complex things and we may find in future that an artificial womb has so many bits of an actual human that it basically *is* a human (or whatever species... see also the nature of the [Tleilaxu females](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bene_Tleilax#Axlotl_tank) in the *Dune* series). A way around the technological complexity and at least *some* of the ethical issues might be to do a kind of production-line IVF and then implant the viable fetuses into non-gamete-producing but otherwise suitably equipped and workers to do the rest of the hard work. There's even scope for a sort of oviposition into workers by a fertilized female, if that's the sort of thing that floats your boat, avoiding the technological stage entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard about [mole rats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_mole-rat)?

[image: Heterocephalus Glaber]

These are the closest thing to an ant-like society in mammals.

They live in underground burrows and form specialized, mostly females, castes - soldier, worker, ...
Among these, the queen is the biggest female and have the privilege of reproducing with males. She secretes a pheromon that prevent the other females to become fertile. If the queen dies, another female grows and takes her place. They exhibit a bunch of amazing features, including cancer resilience and extra longevity.

**Regarding the artificial techniques**

If for some reasons your race cannot bear their own children, they could use genetic engineering to repurpose another species as living wombs. They would need to improve the target species' compatibility with their own genetic material, [a step already ongoing](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-022-00111-9) in real-life research for organ transplants from pigs.

You would also require to create fertilized eggs. Except if your species is able to do parthenogenesis, this would require a bit more engineering. Fortunately, that's also a [feat](https://www.statnews.com/2022/08/01/synthetic-mouse-embryos-created-from-stem-cells-without-sperm-eggs-uterus/) from real-life research, where mouse embryo where created without sperm, eggs and womb.
In a few words, almost every cell of an organism contain the whole of its genetic code and hence all of the instruction required to build a new individual. The difference between a skin cell and a germ cell resides in how is packaged their DNA - which sections of the genetic code are actually read or not. By carefully repackaging the DNA (it takes a lengthy, delicate procedure involving a cocktail of viruses and drugs), one can force any cell of the body back to the fertilized egg stage, and from there to start a new embryo.